# OnChange pagination api call return data and my page go to top Any solution?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I am implementing pagination at the bottom of page in a table when i change page a api call is sent and when api response return data my page look like refreshed every time
it should be stay at bottom not go to top

Answer (score 1):

You can create a ref using useRef hook,

```
const paginationRef = useRef(null);
```

and pass that ref to pagination element. So, when the api call will complete you can just push at the ref which is pagination actually by using,

```
apiCall().then(() => paginationRef?.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' }))
```

So, this way your current position will point to the pagination whenever api call will hits or refreshed.

Comment: But i am using class component

Comment: `class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}`

Reference link: [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs)